# Transparent/dim ListView background - I want to destroy ListView activity when clicking on background

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` list that operates nicely. It's set this way:

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme"> 
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true </item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:padding="0dp" 
   android:background="@drawable/button_pressed"
   android:clickable="false"
   android:id="@+id/ListViewLayout" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also have a block of code which creates my `ListView` and handles my clicks:

```
public class RandomList extends ListActivity {
    static final String[] randomList = new String[] {"Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 3", "Logo"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new RandomArrayAdapter(this, randomList));
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        //Get selected items
        Log.v("ListView l:", l.toString());
        Log.v("View v:", v.toString());
        Log.v("Position:", ""+position);
        Log.v("ID: ", ""+id);
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Name", selectedValue);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent();
        mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Now, with the `ArrayAdapter` et al, what happens is I get a list of items. As there are only five items, and due to the style I set for it, most of the screen is dimmed out (the original `Activity`), and only the list is centred. The problem is, I want to finish the `Activity` should someone click on the gray region outside of the list box. I cannot for the life of me figure out how.

I tried to implement an `OnTouchListener`, but `ListView` isn't letting me do so and I can't figure out how to call it for the `LinearLayout` container that surrounds the `TextView`. I'm fairly new to Android, so please dumb it down for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create this xml layout and call it "list_layout.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/my_background"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Then change your `onCreate()` to the following:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    View background = findViewById(R.id.my_background);
    background.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             RamdomList.this.finish();
         }
     });

    setListAdapter(new RandomArrayAdapter(this, randomList));

}
```

I wrote this off the top of my head without running it, so you might fight a few things off but you get the concept.

Comment: Okay,so that works nicely as long as I turn off the style I set for the theme. But when I keep the Theme.Transparent on, it fails. My guess is that the theme causes my_background to wrap around the list, instead of around the entire screen (ie - wrap_content instead of fill_parent), thereby making it so I can't click anywhere. 

How do I keep the window floating, the background dimmed, but with the ability for the entire transparent container to be in the background and stay clickable?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my second question, asked regarding the box. In the `Theme.Transparent`, I just had to turn `WindowIsFloating` to `false`. Combine that with Wnafee's excellent answer and it worked like a charm.